# Incrementing integer value in form of string in TCL

Tags: string, tcl, increment, string-concatenation

Hi I have a `string` variable in tcl that stores some `integer` value. I need to get the left most digit from the `string` variable and increment it by 1. Basically below is the code that I wrote to accomplish my task :

```
set maxID 123456;
if {$maxID < 1000000} {
  set maxID 1000000;
} elseif {$maxID >= 1000000} {
  set maxID [expr [string index $maxID 0] + 1]000000; #Need to Simplify this
}
return $maxID;
```

Now what I am trying to do is if the `maxID` is greater than or equal to 1 million, set the `maxID` to the next million value. So in above example since `maxID` is `123456`, the return `maxID` value should be `1000000` since the next million value for `123456` is `1000000`.

So to do that, I am getting the left most digit which is 1, then increment it by 1 and concat six zeros which will increment the value. I am using tcl 8.5.x so I still don't have `[string cat $args $args...]` command available.

Anyways, I was wondering if there is any simpler way of doing the same.

Comment: According to the code you've posted, the resulting value for `maxID` would be `1123456`, not `2000000`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the maxid value was less than a million.

Comment: So you basically want to round up `maxID` to the nearest multiple of a million, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use string manipulations to do mathematical operations. It requires a special case for values less than `1000000` and it doesn't work correctly for values above `9999999` (E.g., `10000000` results in `2000000` instead of `11000000`).

What you want to do is to round up `maxID` to the nearest multiple of a million. You can do this in very simple code without requiring special case handling by using mathematical operators. In addition, that allows rounding up to multiples of something else than a million with no extra effort:

```
proc roundUp {value {step 1000000}} {
    expr {($value / $step + 1) * $step}
}
```

Here are some examples:

```
> roundUp 0
1000000
> roundUp 123456
1000000
> roundUp 999999
1000000
> roundUp 1000000
2000000
> roundUp 9999999
10000000
> roundUp 10000000
11000000
```

Using a different step than `1000000`:

```
> roundUp 5 6
6
> roundUp 6 6
12
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing seems a buggy way to go about doing that. Much better to make use of the fact that the `%` operator does integer division when presented with integers.

```
if {$maxID >= 1000000} {
    set bigbits [expr {$maxID / 1000000}]
    incr bigbits
    set maxID [expr {$bigbits * 1000000}]
    # Converting the three lines above into one is left as an exercise ;-)
} else {
    incr maxID
}
```

In the simplest case, you might be able to get away with this:

```
if {$maxID >= 1000000} {
    incr maxID 1000000
} else {
    incr maxID
}

# Or:  incr maxID [expr {$maxID >= 1000000 ? 1000000 : 1}]
```

but that depends on the input value already being a well-formed member of the sequence; that might be totally a bad idea.

Comment: You mention the `%` operator but don't use it in your example code... I guess you mean `/` anyway? And also I don't think that `maxID` is supposed to be incremented by 1 if it's less than a million.